# Find the most common number in an array of numbers

Tags: javascript, algorithm, typescript

**Exercise description:**

*Find the most common number in an array of numbers.*

*Create a software that takes an array of numbers as parameter.
The return of the function shall be the most common number.*

*Example: 
Assume that the list is ... 1, 5, 1, 3, 5, 5, 2.*

*The program will output 5, because this is the most common number.*

*Note that if there is more than one most common number, the program
will just print one of the most common numbers.*

**My solution (written in TypeScript):**

```js
let numbers: number[] = [1, 5, 1, 3, 5, 5, 2];

namespace Main {
  export function searchMostCommonNumber(arr: number[] = []): number {
    let current: number = 0;
    let max: number = 0;
    let mostCommonNumber: number = 0;
    let i: number;

    for (i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
      let current: number = 1;
      let j: number;

      for (j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
        if (arr[i] === arr[j]) {
          current++;
        }
      }

      if (current > max) {
        max = current;
        mostCommonNumber = arr[i];
      }
    }

    return mostCommonNumber;
  }
}

console.log(Main.searchMostCommonNumber(numbers));
```

**Live demo (with compiled code):**

```js
var numbers = [1, 5, 1, 3, 5, 5, 2];
var Main;
(function(Main) {
  function searchMostCommonNumber(arr) {
    if (arr === void 0) {
      arr = [];
    }
    var current = 0;
    var max = 0;
    var mostCommonNumber = 0;
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
      var current_1 = 1;
      var j = void 0;
      for (j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
        if (arr[i] === arr[j]) {
          current_1++;
        }
      }
      if (current_1 > max) {
        max = current_1;
        mostCommonNumber = arr[i];
      }
    }
    return mostCommonNumber;
  }
  Main.searchMostCommonNumber = searchMostCommonNumber;
})(Main || (Main = {}));
console.log('The most common number is :', Main.searchMostCommonNumber(numbers));
```

**What do you think about my solution?**

**Is there a better way to accomplish the task? What would you have done differently?**

Looking forward to reading your comments and answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For small arrays as input your script's performance is very good. Let me show you a different approach which might especially improve readability and might also increase performance for larger inputs and multiple runs.

## `.reduce()`

Instead of iterating through the elements manually, I've used [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=a):

> The `reduce()` method applies a function against an *accumulator* and *each element* in the array (from left to right) to reduce it to a single value.

The function has two steps now which both use `reduce()`:

1. Reduce the input into an object that holds each *number* and its *count* as key/value-pairs.
2. Reduce this object to find the key with the highest value.

---

```
function findMode(numbers) {
    let counted = numbers.reduce((acc, curr) => { 
        if (curr in acc) {
            acc[curr]++;
        } else {
            acc[curr] = 1;
        }

        return acc;
    }, {});

    let mode = Object.keys(counted).reduce((a, b) => counted[a] > counted[b] ? a : b);

    return mode;
}
```

---

### Performance

In the comments we had a lot of discussion about performance about this and other solutions.

One requested improvement was to calculate the `mode` directly in the first `reduce` call. It could look like this:

```
function findModeAlternative(numbers) {
    let max = 0;
    let mode = null;
    let counted = numbers.reduce((acc, curr) => { 
        if (curr in acc) {
            acc[curr]++;
        } else {
            acc[curr] = 1;
        }

        if (max < acc[curr]) {
            max = acc[curr];
            mode = curr;
        }

        return acc;
    }, {});

    return mode;
}
```

*Unfortunately it didn't improve performance in Chrome and Firefox.*

---

Then [Blindman67](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/120556/blindman67) suggested the naive approach with this solution:

```
function findCommon(arr) {
    var max = 1,
        m = [],
        val = arr[0],
        i, x;

    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) {
        x = arr[i]
        if (m[x]) {
            ++m[x] > max && (max = m[i], val = x);
        } else {
            m[x] = 1;
        }
    } return val;    
}
```

Which will increase performance significantly in Firefox, but performs about the same in Chrome. Keep in mind, that functions like `reduce`, `map` etc. come with some overhead.

---

Finally the approach using `map` in [Gerrit0's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/177987/21444) also increases the performance drastically opposed to the original.

---

### Test

I've created a test, so you can check the performance of each variant yourself. The test uses two different arrays with *ca. 500 elements* each and runs every function *100000* times:

- test array A is kind of mixed
- test array B contains mostly one number with a few exceptions

These are the results from Chrome 61 on macOS:

- array A "findMode": 1000ms
- array B "findMode": 950ms
- array A "findModeAlternative": 1200 ms
- array B "findModeAlternative": 1100 ms
- array A "findCommon": 930 ms
- array B "findCommon": 960 ms
- array A "mostCommonNumber": 1700 ms
- array B "mostCommonNumber": 1300 ms
- array A "searchMostCommonNumber": 12697 ms
- array B "searchMostCommonNumber": 13400 ms

[Try it yourself](https://jsfiddle.net/ddg3320w/)

Of course you can tweak the test and try different inputs etc.

## The functions's name

As this is called [*mode*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics)) in statistics, you could use a shorter function name like `findMode()`

<sup>Unfortunately this doesn't improve performance. This is just a personal preference</sup>

---

<sup>I only included the ES6 version of the script in this answer. I didn't add the check whether the array is an array and not empty, as this will be added when compiling from TypeScript to JavaScript</sup>

Comment: Worth mentioning: `findMode` will throw for an empty array, while the OP's function will not.

Comment: Also, regarding your benchmark, which implementation is faster depends heavily on the type of data you are working with. With a small number of *different* numbers, `findMode` will be faster. With nearly as many different numbers as elements in the array, the implementation using a Map will be faster.

Comment: Loops `for(...`,`while(` outperform iterators `forEach`, `reduce`, `map` at about 2 to 1. Your code also loops over the final reduced array, this is not need as you hold each max when you count them. the max and its number value can be found during the reduction. Applying both improvements the following runs 3 times faster than you findMode function `function findCommon(arr){
    var max = 1, m = [], val = arr[0], i, x;
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++){
        x = arr[i++];
        if (m[x]) { ++m[x] > max && (max = m[idx], val = x) } else { m[x] = 1 }
    }
    return val;
}`

Comment: @Blindman67 You should add this as an answer. It's fast and easy to read. And you're right, every one of those optimized `for`-solutions will be faster than `reduce`, `map` etc. I think I will remove my answer. :D It's kinda biased.

Comment: Don't remove your answer, I have not time at the moment to add an answer, I put it in the comment just to make note of it as the performance increase is substantial.

Comment: OH dear there is a typo in the function that could give you the wrong time result.. `x = arr[i++]`  should be `x = arr[i]`

Comment: And one last improvement. The array created is a sparse array (as indexes are added out of order) the whole function can double the performance if you create a typed array `m = []` becomes `m = new Uint32Array(arr.length);`

Comment: @Blindman67 I added more explanation to the answer as well as your suggested solution, which performs great in Firefox. What do you think about the answer in general now?

Comment: @Gerrit0 I've updated the wording and tests in my answer, to be more clear about perfomance in all solutions. Hope this is OK now - let me know what you think. Sorry if my first version was kinda biased. You already have my upvote, as yours is a very nice review.

Comment: +1 Good stuff. Odd about the alternative `findMode` tests I ran showed 25-30% faster on Chrome, though I used the short form  `if(curr in acc) { ++acc[curr] > max && (max = acc[curr], mode = curr) }` the advantage is not having to index the `acc` array a second time to test against `max` If memory was the bench then a mod on OPs code would be best. As each item is tested non matching items are moved down the array to take the place of the tested numbers. Then each iteration the length of the search is reduced, plus early exit if max > then remaining numbers.

Comment: like for real guys there is a glaring mistake in the code above 
`code  max = m[i] should be m[x]`

Answer (score 3):

My approach would be slightly different.

1. Efficiency, though your current approach is memory efficient, it is `O(n^2)` which will make it rather slow for large arrays.
2. I don't see any reason to include a `namespace`. With module support, namespaces seem to add unnecessary complexity in most cases.
3. Scope variables properly. There's no reason to declare `i` and `j` outside of the loops.
4. Avoid adding types where they can be inferred. `let n: number = 0` can be written as `let n = 0` and Typescript can infer the type of `n` to be `number` without needing to explicitly type it (note that for complex types it is still sometimes a good idea to explicitly state the type).
5. Returning `0` for the empty array seems odd. There is no "most common number" if there are no numbers. Granted, returning `NaN` isn't much better (if it even is better).

Here's how I would implement this function.

```
function mostCommonNumber(numbers: number[]): number {
    let map = new Map<number, number>()
    for (let num of numbers) {
        map.set(num, (map.get(num) || 0) + 1)
    }

    let mostCommonNumber = NaN
    let maxCount = -1
    for (let [num, count] of map.entries()) {
        if (count > maxCount) {
            maxCount = count
            mostCommonNumber = num
        }
    }

    return mostCommonNumber
}
```

Demo:

```js
function mostCommonNumber(numbers) {
    let map = new Map()
    for (let num of numbers) {
        map.set(num, (map.get(num) || 0) + 1)
    }

    let mostCommonNumber = NaN
    let maxCount = -1
    for (let [num, count] of map.entries()) {
        if (count > maxCount) {
            maxCount = count
            mostCommonNumber = num
        }
    }

    return mostCommonNumber
}

let tests = [
  [],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1],
  [1, 5, 1, 3, 5, 5, 2]
]

for (let test of tests) {
  console.log(`[${test}] --> ${mostCommonNumber(test)}`)
}
```